# Establish global variables for javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have inherited a wordpress website that stores the main javascript in a .php file because it uses global variables which are set within other php templates of the site. So for example, the main javascript file uses conditionals relying on php variables like this:

```
<?php if ($GLOBALS['page_class'] == 'news' ?>
      $("foo").someJavaScriptAction();
```

My quest is to re-write this main javascript file to be a pure .js file and not rely on any php. Is there a way I can check for those php variables in a .js file? If not, what could be a strategy for checking these variables in my new .js file?

Comment: Unfortunately, whoever wrote that code did a horrible job. Wordpress has it's own way of handling this, using [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

Comment: You could `var wpvars = <?php echo json_encode($GLOBALS) ?>` inside of a script tag, so that it can be resolved from the `window`. Then traverse the object from your .js file at `window.wpvars`.

Comment: Besides injecting JSON as per the other comments, if the pieces of JS are large, you can split them into .js files, and use [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) to conditionally queue them. You could also use CSS classes to trigger the behaviour - something like `if ( $(".page_class") ) $("foo")....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real, proper way of doing this in Wordpress is with [`wp_localize_script`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) (use this in your theme *functions.php*):

```
function enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('theme-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
    wp_localize_script('theme-script', 'script_vars', array(
        'var1'  => $GLOBALS['var1'],
        'var2'  => $GLOBALS['var2']
    ));
    wp_enqueue_script(theme-script);
}
```

Then to access `var1` in your *script.js* just do the following: `script_vars.var1`

Comment: Are there any limitations to the amount of variables I should use? I mean is there any argument for performance to use less variables? I'm thinking I would use about 10.

Comment: No for that amount of variables it's totally ok. If you would have a lot more, a cleaner solution would have been to `json_encode` it in order to decode it in JS and get a unique object. It would possibly affect performance just with a very large amount of variables, like hundred.